# RabbitMQ ssl connection failing with an error "crashed with reason: no case clause matching false in amqp_direct_connection:ssl_info/1"

Tags: java, ssl, rabbitmq, mqtt

I've made a clean installation of RabbitMQ 3.8.3. I want to connect to it via SSL and MQTT protocol. My active plugins are:

- rabbitmq_management
- rabbitmq_web_dispatch
- rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl
- rabbitmq_management_agent
- rabbitmq_mqtt

I can connect via tcp without issues, using login and password. But when I try to connect via SSL, there is a crash on Rabbit side with the following error message:

```
crashed with reason: no case clause matching false in amqp_direct_connection:ssl_info/1
```

This is the same whether I have a correct client certificate or not.

My config is:

```
listeners.ssl.1                        = 5671
auth_mechanisms.1            = EXTERNAL
auth_mechanisms.2            = PLAIN
auth_mechanisms.3            = AMQPLAIN
mqtt.listeners.ssl.default       = 8883
mqtt.allow_anonymous             = false
mqtt.ssl_cert_login              = true
ssl_cert_login_from              = common_name

ssl_options.verify               = verify_peer
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = true
ssl_options.cacertfile           = [path]
ssl_options.certfile             = [path]
ssl_options.keyfile              = [path]
ssl_options.password               = [pass]

ssl_options.honor_cipher_order   = true
ssl_options.honor_ecc_order      = true
```

Could anyone suggest what is causing this and how to solve it?

I've already tried reinstalling RabbitMQ, deleting and recreating the user, changing certificates.

Comment: Hello, thanks for using RabbitMQ but version 3.8.x is no longer supported. Please use the latest version! PS if you can reproduce this issue using the latest version of RabbitMQ and Erlang, let us know here - https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues